# Passing a image size variable using Javascript to a PHP page

Tags: php, javascript

### I am trying to send a canvas drawing to the server using javscript.

Having a function such as :

```
function uploadPic() {              
    var imgData = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
    window.location = "myPHPfile.php?imageData=" + imgData;
}
```

What would the best way to pass the **imgData** variable to the php page due to its large size. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User post request to pass large data. You can use jQuery post method

```
$.post('myPHPfile.php', { imageData: imgData }, function(data) {
    // completed
});
```

Or create and post form:

```
function uploadPic() {              
    var imgData =  document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "myPHPfile.php";
    var hidden = document.createElement('input');
    hidden.type = 'hidden';
    hidden.name = 'imageData';
    hidden.value = imgData;
    form.appendChild(hidden);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```